# wrong ELF class for python 2.7 (32-bit ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: python

I installed Acestream and found that acestreamengine won't run.

Trying to start acestreamengine, I get this output:

```
2015-05-10 12:19:52,008|MainThread|acestream|error during startup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core.c", line 1107, in 
  File "core.c", line 48, in 
  File "core.c", line 25, in 
  File "/usr/share/acestream/lib/psutil-1.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/psutil/__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/acestream/lib/psutil-1.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/acestream/lib/psutil-1.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_psutil_linux.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/acestream/lib/psutil-1.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_psutil_linux.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: /home/marius/.python-eggs/psutil-1.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/_psutil_linux.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

---

```
root@Mariubuntu:/# find -type f -name "ace*.deb"
./var/cache/apt/archives/acestream-engine_3.0.3-1trusty1_i386.deb
./var/cache/apt/archives/acestream-full_3.0.2-1trusty1_i386.deb
./var/cache/apt/archives/acestream-player_3.0.2-1trusty1_i386.deb
./var/cache/apt/archives/acestream-player-data_3.0.2-1trusty2_i386.deb
./var/cache/apt/archives/acestream-mozilla-plugin_3.0.2-1trusty1_i386.deb
root@Mariubuntu:/# find -type f -name "ace*.deb" -print0 | xargs -0 -I  {} dpkg -x {} acestream
dpkg-deb: feil: klarte ikke lese arkivet «{}»: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog
dpkg-deb: feil: klarte ikke lese arkivet «{}»: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog
dpkg-deb: feil: klarte ikke lese arkivet «{}»: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog
dpkg-deb: feil: klarte ikke lese arkivet «{}»: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog
dpkg-deb: feil: klarte ikke lese arkivet «{}»: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog
```

Sorry it's in norwegian, but it reads "dpkg-deb: error: cannot read archive "{}": no such file or directory.

---

apparently there's something i don't understand. i moved the .python-eggs directory like you said. reinstalled acestream. the 32-bit libs are in the acestream/usr/share/acestream/lib/ directory, still same error when trying to run acestreamengine..

Comment: You need the 32-bit version.

Comment: i know, but how? 32-bit version of python 2.7 right?

Comment: In the DEB packages of acestream:i386 for Trusty are 32-bit libs. I checked.

Comment: You have a 32-bit system, right? Your title says "(32-bit ubuntu 14.04)"

Comment: yes,  it's a 32-bit system. what do i type instead of the "{}" in the extraction command?

Comment: Nothing. `{}` means `{}`. This will automatically be replaced by the result of the search. :)

Comment: ok, so i got the same result with the commands you posted, but how does this help me, i still get the same output trying to start acestreamengine

Comment: I have made a proposal in the first part of my answer. In the second part I have described what I did. The second part is for the understanding.

Comment: apparently there's something i don't understand. i moved the .python-eggs directory like you said. reinstalled acestream. the 32-bit libs are in the acestream/usr/share/acestream/lib/ directory, still same error when trying to run acestreamengine...

Answer (score 0):

Move the folder `/home/marius/.python-eggs/` with

```
mv /home/marius/.python-eggs /home/marius/.python-eggs.bak
```

and install acestream again from this repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://repo.acestream.org/ubuntu/ trusty main"
sudo wget -O - http://repo.acestream.org/keys/acestream.public.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall acestream*
```

---

In the DEB packages of acestream*:i386 for Trusty are 32-bit libs (i686).

I checked:

I have downloaded all deb packages:

```
$ find -type f -name "ace*.deb"                                   
./acestream-player-data_3.0.2-1trusty2_i386.deb
./acestream-player_3.0.2-1trusty1_i386.deb
./acestream-full_3.0.2-1trusty1_i386.deb
./acestream-player/usr/share/acestreamplayer/acestream-player-data_3.0.2-1trusty2_i386.deb
./acestream-engine_3.0.3-1trusty1_i386.deb
```

and extracted:

```
find -type f -name "ace*.deb" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} dpkg -x {} acestream

$ ls -go acestream/usr/share/acestream/lib/
insgesamt 1500
drwxr-xr-x 2    4096 Okt 31  2014 acestreamengine
-rw-r--r-- 1   96943 Okt 31  2014 bitarray-0.8.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
-rw-r--r-- 1  129811 Okt 31  2014 blist-1.3.4-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
-rw-r--r-- 1   32506 Okt 31  2014 GeoIP-1.3.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
-rw-r--r-- 1   29233 Okt 31  2014 miniupnpc-1.9-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
-rw-r--r-- 1  146129 Okt 31  2014 psutil-1.2.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
-rw-r--r-- 1 1086544 Okt 31  2014 pycompat27.so
```

Comment: that's what i did...